# How to display date and time value in JSF's data table?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Data table in JSF displays the value of time stamp data type in MON dd,YYYY. But I also want to include hh:mm:ss. Please help.

Comment: What format pattern have you provided?  I'd recommend the ISO standard yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS

Comment: Could we see how you are formatting the time stamp to see why you are not able to include the time part. This is complicated to see for the moment. So you might want to see about [mcve]

Comment: I am not formatting the timestamp. I am simply displaying a date time value whose Java datatype in the underlying bean is timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display date and time in datatable similar to following example:

```
<p:column id="activityDate" headerText="#{msg.date}">
    <h:outputText value="#{res.activityDate}">
        <f:convertDateTime timeZone="#{referenceData.timezone}"
            pattern="MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
    </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

Comment: @Kukeltje There is no code in question. I propose version how to reach expected format.

Comment: There **should** be code in a question. See [ask]. otherwise doing a search on 'how to format date in jsf' in google and finding the duplicates in stackoverflow and marking thos as a duplicate would have been better

Comment: Thanks for the help.It displays the timestamp in correct format now. But I need to change this in my entire project. What can be the possible reason for this issue? Earlier it displayed correctly without using :<f:convertDateTime timeZone="#{referenceData.timezone}"
            pattern="MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss" />.